# Canonic identification $T_{I_n}\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently studying Lie Groups and have a questions about this:

Let $x_{ij} : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
      ~~~~~~~A \mapsto A_{ij}$

Then it says let $f$ be *the canonic identification*
$$f: T_{I_n}\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}) \\
f(A)_{ij} = A(x_{ij}) ~~~ \forall A \in T_{I_n}\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$$

I would like to know what *canonic identification* means in this context. I appreciate any help.

Comment: "Canonical" means literally God-given. It means the only obvious thing you could write down. ... But I don't understand the notation of what you wrote. Shouldn't the right-hand side be $x_{ij}(A)$? Remember that you're just working with a vector space, and they're saying that you can identify the tangent space of a vector space at any point with the vector space itself.

Comment: Thanks! I took this from my lecture notes there could very well be a mistake. I thought it was meant in the following way: If A is a tangent vector then it maps smooth functions onto $\mathbb{R}$ so $A(x_{ij})$ should be a real number which is the $ij$-th component of $f(A)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: But you've defined $x_{ij}$ as a function on matrices. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is meant is that for a vector space $V$ (such as $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb R)$), and a point $x\in V$, there is a natural identification of $T_xV$ with $V$. From your comment I take it that you prefer to view tangent vectors as operators on functions. In this language, the identification maps $v\in V$ to the directional derivative at $x$ in direction $v$, i.e. to the operator $\phi\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\phi(x+tv)$, which is an element of $T_xV$.